# Log4j Appender that logs messages to a list/map

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, java-11, appender

I'm looking for a log4j appender that logs all messages (according to appender configuration of course) to a list/map object in memory.
A list/map that I have access to in my code and read the messages from there later on.

Is there such a known open source implementation or do I need to implement my own appender?

Note: I saw this example of MapAppender, but I thought of using a 3rd party instead of implementing my own - https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender

Thanks,
Lin

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for https://gist.github.com/crevier/a2fd46e1a39acb06da7a6e6e2eee48a4 However, writing to the list/map is a part of the story, the real question is what would like like to do with this data, who will read it and how? Depending on your requirements you might consider using Apache Flume that can provide in-memory transaction-like semantics and can be embedded into your application, of maybe use some kind of mocking for the logger itself if your purpose is testing...

Comment: @MarkBramnik I need to send all the events from time to time to a main location that processes the data. Later on it might be per request, but this can be handled by adding the thread id etc. to the map. I will need access to the map used. I'll take a look at what you've suggested.